# Is there a way how to "encode" PHP array into PHP code?

Tags: php, arrays

for very special purpose I need to transform PHP array into PHP code. I will try to explain what I mean in code below:

```
$a = array('a' => 'abc', 'path' => INCLUDE_DIR.'/file.txt', 'number' => 1234);
$php_code = some_magic_function($a);
echo $php_code; // outputs: "array('a' => 'abc', 'path' => '/path/to/file.txt', 'number' => 1234)"
```

So it would write back array as PHP code. I can not find any library that would help me with this.

Any ideas or hints ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `$php_code  = var_export($a, true);`? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Qirel I think you can write an answer

Comment: Out of interest, what is the very special purpose for doing this? I wonder whether someone might have a better suggestion to solve the problem.

Comment: There can be plenty of use case, creating dynamically migration scripts, generating some code for bug reproduction ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to print the array as a string, in the exact format it would be written in your code.

If so, then the [var_export()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) function is what you need, e.g. something like this:

```
$a = array('a' => 'abc', 'path' => '/file.txt', 'number' => 1234);
$str = var_export($a, true);
echo $str;
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0b1da8fc0199a34539a55313680e982f9fddd14f

Comment: So many years with PHP and never knew about this function :-(

Comment: @Frodik I didn't know of that function neither. The things we learn :)

Comment: SO taught me that function, when someone was posting a question about php arrays and someone in comment asked to use `var_export()` instead of `var_dump()`, for easier reproducibility